# How do I fix and fit all the information to stay inside the table?

Tags: css

How do I make all the information stay and fit inside the table,
other than using the `style="overflow:scroll"`?

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPLQO.png)
as in the picture it got overflow to the right in the middle of the `LATEST DATE CHECKED`.

Below is my code.

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-indent: initial;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="nk-block">
  <div class="card card-bordered">
    <table class="table table-voucher">
      <thead class="tb-voucher-head">
        <tr class="tb-voucher-title">
          <th class="tb-voucher-date tb-col-md">
            <span>DATE</span>
          </th>
          <th class="tb-voucher-seen tb-col-md">
            <span>LATEST DATE CHECKED</span>
          </th>
          <th class="tb-voucher-status tb-col-md ">
            <span>STATUS</span>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="tb-voucher-body" id="voucher_content"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add the css code too

Comment: We'll definitely need the css. The image seems to show only two 'tabs' for the table headers, so something is going on there. You'll probably find your browser's Inspector useful to see exactly what's going on with these elements.

Comment: updated the code. seems like the card got the problem ?

Comment: @teefal Isn't there more code for the css "tb-voucher-title" and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried something and now its look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
thead {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    border-radius: 4px;
}

table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-indent: initial;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
    }
    
 th {
    padding: 13px;
 }
 
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nk-block">
            <div class="card card-bordered">
                <table border="1">
                    <thead class="tb-voucher-head">
                        <tr>
                            <th>DATE</th>
                            <th>LATEST DATE</th>
                            <th>CHECKED</th>
                            <th>STATUS</th>                        
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in which line should i put the padding-right ?

Comment: wait im going to try